# What is the best way to say "fresh baked cookie"?

Tags: translation

https://translate.google.com/#auto/zh-CN/fresh%20baked%20cookie
Google says:
新鲜烤饼干

but I know 饼干 to be cracker.
Is there a better term to describe a fresh baked cookie?

Comment: alternatives, see jukuu：烘焙饼干，新烤的饼干

Comment: to confirm 新鲜烤 simply feed this to jukuu, and get example:...也许是新鲜烤面包的味道...

Comment: naturally for different English expressions (with similar meaning) jukuu will have alternatives, e.g. feed "fresh from oven" and get 4 example sentences: e.g 4.  The pie is fresh from the oven.
 这个派是刚从烤箱拿出来的。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Cookies' can be translated as '小甜餅' ; describe as '牛油小酥餅' ; transliterated to '**曲奇**'(often: '曲奇餅')

To say "fresh baked cookie" in Chinese:

新鲜烤的小甜餅 / 新鲜烤的曲奇餅 (fresh baked cookie)

*can be simplified to 新鲜烤小甜餅 / **新鲜烤曲奇** (fresh baked cookie)

剛出烤箱的小甜餅 /剛出烤箱的曲奇餅 (fresh out of the oven cookie)

> 曲奇 http://www.xiachufang.com/category/51906/

Answer (score 10):

The following information is provided for reference.

We use 剛出爐的 or 現烤的 for "fresh baked" in Taiwan.

Therefore, "fresh baked cookie" may be called as follows in Taiwan.
剛出爐的餅乾 ／ 現烤的餅乾
剛出爐的麵包 ／ 現烤的麵包
剛出爐的甜點 ／ 現做的甜點

It's very common to see these signs in Taiwan.
剛出爐的麵包
剛出爐的饅頭
剛出爐的包子
剛出爐的披薩

Comment: 麵包, 饅頭, 包子 and 披薩  are supposed to be eaten when they are warm, therefore you see 出爐麵包 signs in Hong Kong everywhere, but  曲奇 is mostly eaten at room temperature, 剛出爐的曲奇 can only be enjoyed at home where you bake it yourself. As for the fresh baked cookie you can buy in bakeries, people usually don't care if it is fresh out of the oven or not, they only care about if it is  flaky and crunch, the bakeries usually promote their cookies as 酥脆曲奇

Answer (score 1):

It's simply 现烤饼干 or 现烤曲奇.

Hinen mentioned 刚出炉的, it's correct but too complicated in my view.

Answer (score 0):

曲奇 is only used in Hong Kong, it is a pronunciation translation of 'cookie'. It is not a 'mainstream' Chinese that can be understand across China.

Comment: Nah, 曲奇 is widely used in many regions in southern China.